# null is not an object (evalutating 'RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus')

Tags: react-native, calendar

I'm trying to put an event in Calendar phone with this package "import RNCalendarEvents from 'react-native-calendar-events';"
 But I've this error "null is not an object (evalutating 'RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus')"

```
import RNCalendarEvents from 'react-native-calendar-events
onPressAdd() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus()
                .then(status => {
                    console.log(status)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I did not add dependencies to iOS android when I installed the module.

You try run `react-native link react-native-calendar-events`

### Editing

Please delete the module and try to install it from scratch.

1. `npm install --save react-native-calendar-events`
2. `react-native link react-native-calendar-events`

**Usage**

```js
import RNCalendarEvents from 'react-native-calendar-events';
RNCalendarEvents.authorizationStatus()
```

If this is not possible, it may not be available because it is a previously made module.

If you are checking permissions on a calendar, you can replace it with this module.

```js
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
async function checkPermission() {
write_calender = await PermissionsAndroid.WRITE_CALENDAR
read_calender = await PermissionsAndroid.READ_CALENDAR
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.check(write_calender) && 
    granted === PermissionsAndroid.check(read_calender)) {
      console.log('You can use the CALENDAR');
    } else {
      console.log('CALENDAR permission denied');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this command line but I've the same issue

Comment: @Speed2011 I modified my answer to your comments.

Comment: I try these instructions but I've the same issue, I've already the permission for the calendar. I try to use this package to put an event in the phone calendar